# Normalization of the square of Green's function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, greens-functions, normalization

I am trying to normalize 4x4 matrix ($g$ and $f$ are functions):

\begin{equation}
G=\left(\begin{matrix}
(1-g^2) &0& 0& 0&\\
0& (1+f^2)& (-g^2-f^2)& 0 \\
0 &(-g^2-f^2)& (1+f^2)& 0 &\\
0& 0& 0& (1-g^2)
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{equation}

It's a matrix that's in a research paper (which I don't have)  which gives the normalization constant as: $N=4-2g^2+2f^2$.

So far I know heard three methods:

1. $N=\sqrt{\sum{X^2}}$ where $X$ represents the elements of the matrix.
2. Find the determinant.
3. The ratio between the integral of excited state matrix and the integral of normal state of the matrix.

For Method 1, I'm getting as far as:
$$N^2 = 4(1+f^4+f^2g^2+f^2).$$
So I backtracked to see if their $N^2$ matches my $N^2$. But their 
$$N^2=16+4g^4+4f^4+16g^2-8g^2f^2+16f^2.$$

Note that normalization must satisfy the following condition: $G^2=1$. Any comments about all methods mentioned and how to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an example of a density matrix that needs to be normalized. A density matrix is normalized if its trace gives 1. The trace of $G$ gives 
$$ {\rm tr} \{G\} = 4-2g^2-2f^2 . $$
So, to get a normalized density matrix one needs to divide $G$ by its trace.
$$ \rho = \frac{G}{{\rm tr} \{G\}} . $$
Note however that a density matrix needs to be pure to give ${\rm tr} \{\rho^2\}=1$. Not sure if this is what you referred to by requiring $G^2=1$.

If the density matrix is pure, then it can be written as $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$, where $|\psi\rangle$ is normalized in the sense that $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle=1$. Then it follows directly that
$$ \rho^2 = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\psi\rangle\langle\psi| = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi| = \rho . $$
Since ${\rm tr} \{\rho\}=1$, it then also means that ${\rm tr} \{\rho^2\}=1$.

Comment: I unintentionally asked two questions.  You answered correctly the first part.  Indeed, this is a trace of $G$ that gives the normalization. I do not understand what do you mean by 'matrix needs to be pure'.  The second question is about different normalization which is $G^2=1$ condition must be satisfied.  How do I normalized the whole G then, whithout going through trace.  What is the method available to do that?

Comment: For a density matrix, normalization implies that its trace must be 1. This is based on the need to conserve proability. If there is some other way in which a matrix needs to be normalized then that depends on the context. Obvious that would probably then not be in the context of density matrices. Do you have such a context? What do you mean by having the *whole* G normalized?

Comment: Okay, if trace is enough to normalize G matrix then thats fine.  I though trace does normalize diagonal part only or entire matrix if it has triangular symmetry, say upper triangle is the same as lower triangle of matrix.